# I get trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in BUT CANNOT EVEN LOGIN

Tags: php, wordpress, header

I get the warning on top of the page Warning [ClaudiaYoga.com]
: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas08_data03/52/2510952/html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php on line 92

> But the worst part is **I CANNOT LOGIN!!!**

When I try to login it gives me this:

```
>Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas08_data03/52/2510952/html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php on line 92
>Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/p3pnexwpnas08_data03/52/2510952/html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php:92) in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas08_data03/52/2510952/html/wp-login.php on line 387
>Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/p3pnexwpnas08_data03/52/2510952/html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php:92) in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas08_data03/52/2510952/html/wp-login.php on line 400
>Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/p3pnexwpnas08_data03/52/2510952/html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php:92) in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas08_data03/52/2510952/html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 955
>Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/p3pnexwpnas08_data03/52/2510952/html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php:92) in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas08_data03/52/2510952/html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 956
>Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/p3pnexwpnas08_data03/52/2510952/html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php:92) in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas08_data03/52/2510952/html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 957
>Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/p3pnexwpnas08_data03/52/2510952/html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php:92) in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas08_data03/52/2510952/html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1228
```

Comment: rather than showing ALL the errors, why don't you post some *relevant* code and leave the guesswork out of things, we have **nothing** to work with here. Oh, and Google those errors before posting. It would have most likely avoided all this.

Comment: Here, read up on `trim()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php and then read up on your headers sent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php and you can fix it yourself. There's nothing else we can do here for you, sorry.

Comment: you can remove all the `Warning: Cannot modify header information` as they are showing up because of the output from the first error...  fix the first error and the rest will vanish.

Comment: as to the problem, get with your hosting provider and have them look at `/home/content/p3pnexwpnas08_data03/52/2510952/html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php` on line 92

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your $string variable is a string
For exe.
$login = "login_name";
Not
$login = array("login")

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do here is to login to your host cPanel via ftp and rename the plugin file to see which plugin is actually causing the problem. Claudia , I see that you are not tech savvy but you can get this problem solved either by getting a wordpress expert and maybe contact your host.